# push created object with class into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

I ran into this problem with my code.
I want to push the created objects into an array and then display them.
The problem is that the newly created object are overwrite the old ones, I still have issues with pushing objects into array.

My aim is to create inputs and grab their values and through classes I create object then push them into array, loop and display them on the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-   scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="title" />
    <input type="text" id="author" />
    <input type="number" id="pages" />
    <h1>title :</h1>
    <h2>Author :</h2>
    <h3>Pages :</h3>
    <button>Submit</button>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>





const title = document.querySelector("#title");
const author = document.querySelector("#author");
const pages = document.querySelector("#pages");
const submit = document.querySelector("button");
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
const h3 = document.querySelector("h3");

let myLibrary = [];

let Book = class {
  constructor(title, author, pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.words = [];
  }
};

submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (title.value === "" || author.value === "" || pages.value === "") {
    return;
  }

  if (title.value && author.value && pages.value) {
    myLibrary.push(new Book(title.value, author.value, pages.value));
  }
  title.value = "";
  author.value = "";
  pages.value = "";
  myLibrary.forEach((e) => {
    h1.innerHTML = e.title;
    h2.innerHTML = e.author;
    h3.innerHTML = e.pages;
  });
  console.log(myLibrary);
});
```

Comment: So this line of code is running multiple times in a row: `h1.innerHTML = e.title;`. Basically the second will override the first etc. What is `e`: `myLibrary.forEach((e)`?

Comment: actually not because they are different h1 / h2 / h3 and e.title / e.author / e.pages..

Comment: Add a `console.log(e)` in the `.forEach()` (or use the debugger to step through your script) and you will see the problem.

Comment: They appear next to each other as if everything okay but when I press submit the newest one will overwrite the old one, not stuck next to it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here I create list items for each book in the array. I have an empty string and I add alle the books to it and override the `<ul>` in the end.

```js
const book = document.forms.book;
const books = document.getElementById('books');

let myLibrary = [];

const Book = class {
  constructor(title, author, pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.words = [];
  }
};

book.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  myLibrary.push(new Book(e.target.title.value, e.target.author.value, e.target.pages.value));
  e.target.reset();
  let str = '';
  myLibrary.forEach(book => {
    str += `<li>${book.title}, ${book.author}, ${book.pages}</li>`;
  });
  books.innerHTML = str;
});
```

```html
<form name="book">
  <lable>Title: <input name="title" type="text" required></lable>
  <lable>Author: <input name="author" type="text" required></lable>
  <lable>Pages: <input name="pages" type="text" required></lable>
  <button>Save</button>
</form>

<ul id="books"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Just need help in something, why pushing objects into array, the results are rendered like this : first object - ( first - second object ) - ( first - second - third ), this confuses me a lot any idea ?

Comment: @Joey there are different approaches, but this one is fairly simple. You could split it out into more functions. Like a function for rendering all books. So if you have a list of books it is easy to render them.

Answer (score 1):

You insert the info of each book on the same elements (h1,h2,h3)

I suggest you create a container and new h1,h2,h3 for each book:

//You can ommit the forEach, so the below elements are created only for the last added book, not all the books.

// or you can empty the main books list container (here body), then do the forEach and create below elements for all books every time (not good performance wise)

```
  submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (title.value === "" || author.value === "" || pages.value === 
 "") {
  return;
}

 if (title.value && author.value && pages.value) {
 myLibrary.push(new Book(title.value, author.value, pages.value));
 }


let container=document.createElement("div")
let titleDisplayer=document.createElement("h1")
let authorDisplayer=document.createElement("h2")
let pagesDisplayer=document.createElement("h3")

   titleDisplayer.innerHTML = title.value;
   authorDisplayer.innerHTML = author.value;
   pagesDisplayer.innerHTML = pages.value;

container.append(titleDisplayer,authorDisplayer,pagesDisplayer)
document.body.append(container)
 
     title.value = "";
     author.value = "";
     pages.value = "";

console.log(myLibrary);
```

});

Comment: Thanks erfan for answering, just wondering why the the results are going to be rendered twice. For example I created the first object and it is displayed, then when I create another object to display it, the result as follow will be shown , the first one repeated twice and the second one, why the repeated values ?

Comment: It was because everytime you created a new book, new containers were being made for all existing books. I omitted the forEach and it works now. another solution is that you keep the forEach, but empty your document.body everytime before the forEach.